# Scaling of font size with control size of a VBA user form control

Tags: vba, excel

I want to resize a VBA user form when it is displayed on a screen with different resolution. There does not seem to be a built in function for that.
Therefore use some code which multiplies the Top, Left, Width, Height and Font.Size with the same factor, say 50%. However, this changes the appearance of the control: the text does not fit anymore in the area. This has nothing to do with the VBA code, because you get the same when you do the scaling by Hand:

- Create an Option Button with Width 120, Height 24, Font Tahoma 16, Caption "abcdefghijklm" on a user form in Excel 2010.
- Copy the Button and change properties: Width 60, Height 12, Font Tahoma 8. Now part of the text is missing (the letter m) and the bottom of the letters is invisible.

I guess this is because the Control contains not only caption text but also the option button itself and some margins? Anyway my question is: How can I calculate the optimal scaling factor for the caption font.

Comment: Just something else to keep in mind. It isn't always the resolution that is causing the issue. Sometimes it is the scaling the user chooses in the windows settings (i.e. 150% or 200% instead of 100%). Both resolution and scaling require different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not gonna be easy to fix using Tahoma so don't use it, use a mono-spaced font instead.

Find the width of a CHAR as a ratio of its pt (6,7,8,10,12,14,16 etc)

Ratio seems to be about 1.8 for Dejavu Sans Mono

then use

```
(width of button - margins)  / len(text) = width of letter
 width of letter * ptToFontRatio = pt size
```

Button 120px wide with 13 chars as above

```
(120-9)/13 = 8.53
 8.53 * 1.8=  15.3  = closest smaller pt = 14pt
```

Button 60px wide with 13 chars as above

```
(60-9)/13 = 3.92
3.92 * 1.8 = 7.056  - closest smaller pt =  7pt
```

**Note: its always gonna be approx when working these out so round things down to suit**